# How to centre words in add_artist Text in matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, text

How to centre words in add_artist Text in matplotlib?

```
from matplotlib.text import Text 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

fig.add_artist(Text(0.4, 0.6, text=r"Hello" "\n" r"world!!!!!!!")) 

plt.show()
```

The output is left aligned.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with this method?

Comment: I added the picture. I got left-aligned text.

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the parameter `horizontalalignment='center'`. The documentation for Text Layout can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/text_layout.html) if you need it for future reference.

```
from matplotlib.text import Text 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

fig.add_artist(Text(0.5, 0.5, text=r"Hello" "\n" r"world!!!!!!!", horizontalalignment='center')) 

plt.show()
```

[image]